# How to evaluate uncertainty of solution of over-determined system using least square method?

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

I'm trying to solve the over-determined system of linear form:

$$
Ax = b
$$

I know we can consider the problem as a least-square regression[1]:

$$
min_x \|Ax - b\|
$$

and the solution is

$$
x = (A^\top A)^{-1}A^\top b
$$

But I don't know how accurate this approximation is.
How to properly evaluate the uncertainty of x of this solution?

Also appreciate if you share some article about this theory.

---

Note:

I found related answer[2]. According to the article, the covariance matrix of x is calculated as

$$
C_x = (A^\top A)^{-1}A^\top C_b A (A^\top A)^{-1}
$$

If it is true, then, how can we set covariance matrix of b ($C_b$)?
Just calculating standard deviation of $\|Ax - b\|$ (we denote this as $\sigma$) and set $C_b = eye(\sigma^2)$ is O.K.?

- [1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overdetermined_system#Approximate_solutions
- [2] https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/59949

Comment: How do you quantify accuracy>

Comment: I want to qualify standard deviation of x. Does this make sense?